# How to Regex split correctly on entire pattern in positive lookahead (question mark equals)

Tags: .net, regex

I would like to split on all instances of a `<p>` tag followed by a sequence of the same uppercase character followed by a period. For example `<p>A.` and `<p>BB.` would match, but `<p>a.`, `<p>AB.`, `<p>Aa.`, and `<p>C` would not. This is the regex I have (I am using .NET):

`(?=<p>\s*([A-Z])\1*\.)`

The issue is that the split list is

1. `A`
2. `<p>A.`

when it should just be 1. `<p>A.` (I want the matched pattern to be included in the split list which is the reason for having the positive lookahead).

I believe this is due to the parentheses around `([A-Z])` which are necessary to create the capture group to match on the same character using `\1`. I am using http://regexstorm.net/tester to test this out.

Comment: Yes, all captures are output as part of the resulting array when capturing groups are present in the regex.

Comment: Yeah so the issue is there are really two kinds of captures at play: the entire pattern match to be included in the split list, and the singular character to make sure it's the same letter being repeated. There's no way to differentiate them and just have the entire match in the split list?

Comment: The only regex I can come up with is `(?=<p>\s*(?:A+|B+|C+|D+|E+|F+|G+|H+|I+|J+|K+|L+|M+|N+|O+|P+|Q+|R+|S+|T+|U+|V+|W+|X+|Y+|Z+)\.)`, though it's not very pretty or scalable.

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/mlGFWw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may actually use the regex to *match* the locations in the string and append substrings from the previous found index:

```
var text = "<p>AI.For example <p>A.I<p>BB.";
var result = new List<string>();
var rx = new Regex(@"(?=<p>\s*([A-Z])\1*\.)");   // The zero-length matching regex used in Regex.Split
var idx = 0;
foreach (Match m in rx.Matches(text)) {           // Iterate over all matches
    result.Add(text.Substring(idx, m.Index-idx)); // Add item to resulting array
    idx = m.Index;
}
if (idx < text.Length - 1) {         // Add trailing text after last match if present
    result.Add(text.Substring(idx));
}
```

Output:

```
<p>AI.For example 
<p>A.I
<p>BB.
```

Or, use the regex you used for `Regex.Split` to *repace with some rare character*, say `\uFFFF` invalid UTF8 char, and then split with that char:

```
var text = "aaa<p>AI.For example <p>A.I<p>BB.b";
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?=<p>\s*([A-Z])\1*\.)", "\uFFFF");
var result = text.Split('\uFFFF');
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", result)); // => [aaa<p>AI.For example, <p>A.I, <p>BB.b]
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/33mMfA).

Comment: Thanks, this is a clever solution that I like. Unfortunately I'm restricted by having to use a shared base class which uses `Regex.Split` in a way I can't modify to the effect in your answer, but I'm marking it as accepted because it should work otherwise.

Comment: @Drew Well, I shared these approaches as `Regex.Split` behavior with capturing groups cannot be redefined :( I was trying a *matching* approach, but I came across a bug (or a "feature") with how .NET regex treats consecutive zero-length matches.